# Enqueued admin javascript for plugin settings page not executing

Tags: plugins, scripts

Here is how I am enqueueing the script (this is inside a class):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'add_admin_scripts'), true);

public function add_admin_scripts(){
    $parentBase = get_current_screen();
    if($parentBase->id == 'toplevel_page_calc-settings'){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'l7w-admin-js', $this->pluginUrl . 'assets/js/admin.min.js');
    }
}
```

Here is the simple script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Works");
    console.log('Works');
});
```

The js is showing and is loaded on the settings page but the `alert()` and the `console.log()` are not executed.

Why am I not seeing the alert or the console.log()?

Comment: You should see an error in your console related to the `$`, WordPress' jQuery object reference is `jQuery`, not `$`.

Comment: I am seeing this warning:
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/javascript`

Comment: oh, you're using `wp_enqueue_style` instead of `wp_enqueue_script`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'l7w-admin-js', $this->pluginUrl . 'assets/js/admin.min.js');

wp_enqueue_script( 'l7w-admin-js', $this->pluginUrl . 'assets/js/admin.min.js');
```